# Suppose $2^n − 1$ is a prime number (that is, a Mersenne prime). Prove that $N = 2^ n−1$ ($2^n −1$) is an even perfect number.

Tags: number-theory

Please help me with this question as this types of questions are likley to appear in my exam. i am very much confused

Comment: What are the divisors of $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ ?

Comment: there are no divisors

Comment: Hum, have a second try...

Comment: the question is asked as it is asked in the book

Comment: I think he meant have a second try at "What are the divisors of $2^{n-1}(2^{n}-1)$"

Comment: From my guess, will it be 2^n

Comment: What are the divisors of $2^n$ ?

Comment: (n1+1)(n2+1)(n3+1) ... (nk+1).

Comment: It is high time that you review the concept of divisor, integer factorization and the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: I think your question should be changed. $(2^n-1)^2$, as you wrote, is not an even and perfect number; but $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is, and only when $n$ is prime, so you'd better call it $p$

Comment: @Riccardo: the OP does not master typesetting. The primality of $n$ is not explicitly required nor stated, it is just a consequence of the primality of $2^n-1$.

Comment: Could it be possible that you correct the title of the question? The formula as it occurs is completely nonsense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $2^n-1=p$. The divisors of $2^{n-1}p$ are $2^ip^j$, with $0\le i\le n-1$ and $0\le j\le1$, i.e. $2^i$ and $2^ip$.

In other words, $1, 2, 4, 8... 2^{n-1}$ and $p, 2p, 4p, 8p... 2^{n-1}p.$

Let us sum these:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^ip=(1+p)\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}2^i=(1+p)(2^n-1)=2^n(2^n-1)=2.N,$$ by the summation formula for geometric series and the definitions of $p$ and $N$.

For example, for $n=3$, $p=7$ and $N$ is $2^2\cdot7=28$.

Divisors: $1, 2, 4$ and $7, 14, 28$.

Sum of the divisors: $(1 + 7)(1+2+4)=8\cdot7=2\cdot28$.

Comment: Remains to prove that the number is even...

Comment: It might be clearer to use $\cdot$ (`\cdot`) as opposed to $.$ as you do for multiplication.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I sometimes use $\times$ (`\times`).

Answer (score 1):

Divisors are since $2^n-1$ is prime
$$1,2,4,8\cdots2^{n-1},2^n-1,2(2^n-1),4(2^n-1)\cdots2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$$
Exclude the last term(by the definition of perfect number).Now grouping them like this $1+2^n-1+2+2(2^n-1)+4(2^n-1)+\cdots+2^{n-2}+2^{n-1}=2^n+2(2^n)+4(2^n)+\cdots+2^{n-1}=2^n(1+2+4+\cdots+2^{n-2})+2^{n-1}=2^n(2^{n-1}-1)+2^{n-1}=2^{2n-1}-2^n+2^{n-1}=2^{2n-1}-(2^n-2^{n-1})=2^{2n-1}-2^{n-1}=2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$